# FFT output with float buffer AudioUnit

Tags: ios, core-audio, audiounit, accelerate-framework

I have a problem with vDSP_zrip & AudioUnit usage and configuration. In fact I
configured AudioUnit to save packed data as float.
I create a circular buffer and when this buffer is full I calculate an fft.
I have a result but I don't understand why fft ouput is bad (cf figure)

AudioUnit configuration :

```
// describe format
AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat;
audioFormat.mSampleRate       = 44100;
audioFormat.mFormatID         = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
audioFormat.mFormatFlags      = kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian|kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked|kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat|kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved;
audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket  = 1;
audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 1; // mono
audioFormat.mBitsPerChannel   = sizeof(float) * 8;
audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame    = audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame * sizeof(float);
audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket   = audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket * audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame;
```

Circular buffer:

```
_audioSample = new AudioSample(8192, 44100);
// in recording callback :
for(int i = 0; i < bufferList.mNumberBuffers; ++i)
{
    if(!status)
    {
        if(_sample->needData())
            _sample->put((float*)bufferList.mBuffers[i].mData,
                    bufferList.mBuffers[i].mDataByteSize);
        [...]
    }
}
```

vDSP call :

```
  // get a split complex vector (real signal divided into an even-odd config
  vDSP_ctoz((COMPLEX *)sample.get(), 2, &_complex, 1, _fftsize);
  vDSP_fft_zrip(_fftsetup, &_complex, 1, _log2n, kFFTDirection_Forward);
  // scale (from vDSP reference)
  float scale = 1.0 / (2.0 * _samples);
  vDSP_vsmul(_complex.realp, 1, &scale, _complex.realp, 1, _fftsize);
  vDSP_vsmul(_complex.imagp, 1, &scale, _complex.imagp, 1, _fftsize);
  _complex.imagp[0] = 0.0;
```

where `_fftsize = _audioSample.capacity()/2`

[image: figure]

Comment: To clarify, what's bad about your output? It looks like pretty reasonable FFT output. What's the input? What's the expected output?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your output looks pretty reasonable, so I'm going to interpret your question as more of a "How do I clean up these results?"

1) You're probably using a rectangular window

This means that you're not doing any [windowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function), which will introduce some noise into your results. vDSP comes with some functions for performing windowing, which you can use like this:

```
// N = number of samples in your buffer
int N = _audioSample.capacity();

// allocate space for a hamming window
float * hammingWindow = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float) * N);

// generate the window values and store them in the hamming window buffer
vDSP_hamm_window(hammingWindow, N, 0);
```

Then, whenever you're about to do your FFT, window your samples first (as in, do this before your vDSP_ctoz call) :

```
 vDSP_vmul(sample.get(), 1, hammingWindow, 1, sample.get(), 1, N);
```

2) You might want to run a magnitude function on your results

This will give you results similar to those you'd see in a standard FFT bar graph music visualizer thing. Do this *after* the FFT:

```
vDSP_zvmags(&_complex, 1, &_complex.realp, 1, _fftsize);
```

After that, _complex.realp will be an array of float values representing the magnitude of each FFT bin.

Comment: Thank you for your respond, I already use `vDSP_zvmags` function but I don't use windwing function, so I apply a hamming window and I get better results.